# How to block all ethernet traffic destined to any MAC address other than the gateway?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, router, security

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate. I want to be invisible on the LAN. It means that other hosts on the same LAN must not be able to see my computer. Based on [this comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45689/how-to-prevent-other-hosts-on-the-same-lan-from-seeing-my-ip-and-host-name#comment74323_45697), I want to block all ethernet traffic destinated to any MAC address other that the gateway. How to configure it in Windows 7?

Comment: Won't make you invisible; traffic can still be seen going by.

Comment: This is pretty specialized requirement, and I doubt that you can do this in Windows without some special driver.

Comment: What you are asking is almost impossible.  It is **completely impossible if you are on wireless, or connected to a hub** instead of a switch.  But can you elaborate about what exactly you are trying to hid from?  Certain levels of privacy may be possible.  But not complete invisibility.

Comment: @Zoredache: I want to hide my IP, hostname and if possible nobody knows I am connected to the LAN.

Answer (score 1):

Run Windows in a VM under Linux, and use `ebtables` under Linux to filter by MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions.

1. Run your Windows machine from inside a hypervisor, I suggest VirtualBox because ...
2. Use the Bridged connection mode (it is trivial to install on VirtualBox, that's why). This is better than NAT because with NAT all traffic will be addressed to your host, while this does not occur with a bridge.
3. Use a VPN, even a commercial one, to encrypt your traffic; this puts the muzzle on sniffers.
4. Use a static IP. This makes you less visible: you will not be listed in the DHCP client list, and you will fall off the arp table quickly when you are silent;
5. Use your firewall to close all ports.
6. Change MAC address to a random value very often; the random value prevents associating your VM to its maker.
7. Use port-knocking to access your VM from outside.